# How do you set a boolean when the mouse is clicked?

Tags: java, mouseevent, jnativehook

What is wrong is when I set the variable isleftmousedown to true it will test it twice when it is tested in a while loop because I tested it with a while loop and you can see this below! If it helps you I am using JNativeHook with this project!

```
public static NativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e) {
    isleftmousedown = true;
}

public static NativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e) {
    isleftmousedown = false;
}
```

This is the loop:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);

        if (isleftmousedown) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be because loop is running faster than the key listener can mutate the values. Or chances are, the key listener is handled on a separate thread, and you have no memory barriers in place, allowing for data races.

Comment: I tested it other classes and things can run at the same time as this while loop!

Comment: Please do not know to fix i dont think that is the problem!